# Partial Views with view models different to the main view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-2

My home-screen has a view model of `DashboardViewModel`. It has PartialViews with their own ViewModels such as `CustomerSearchViewModel` and `SelectProductViewModel`.

All three ViewModels are separate.

When I run the application I get this error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'Invoice.Web.ViewModels.DashboardViewModel', but this dictionary
>   requires a model item of type
>   'Invoice.Web.ViewModels.SearchCustomerWindowVM'.

I wonder what should I do to resolve this issue.

As planned, the Home screen will eventually integrate a lot of PartialViews with their own  view models. Do I declare the Partial-view-models inside the `DashboardViewModel`? or do I simply have a single big `DashboardViewModel` for all partialViews to come?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have your partial view viewmodels as properties of your main viewmodel and call `Html.Partial` and pass these properties.

```
public class DashBoardVM
{
  public string Name { set;get;}
  public CustomerSearchVM CustomerSearch { set; get;}

  public DashBoardVM()
  {
    CustomerSearch =new CustomerSerachVM();
  }
}
```

In your dashboard view,

```
@model DashBoardVM
<h2>@Model.Name</h2>
@Html.Partial("CustomerSearch",Model.CustomerSearch)
```

Assuming CustomerSearch partial view is strongly typed o `CustomerSearchVM` class.

Comment: Thank you this worked; though CustomerSearch is not strongly typed but it has a PartialView in it (for the GridSearchResults), which is strong typed to the CustomerSearchVM.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use Html.Action() or Html.RenderAction().  This allows you to call a completely separate controller from your parent view, and return a completely different, non associated model.  Here is a pretty good explanation on both rendering Partial Views and Actions.  http://www.midnight-coding.com/2013/01/partial-vs-action-vs-renderpartial-vs-renderaction.html